# Как остановить Service, работающий в отдельном потоке?

Tags: java, android

stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)) посылаю, onDestroy() вызывается, но сервис продолжает работать. Метод stopSelf() в потоке сервиса тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: Код пожалуйста!

Comment: фух, разобрался)

Comment: @ЛевСамара63 может вы код приведете, для тех кто тоже столкнется с этой проблемой?

Comment: Я сделал так: в MainActivity завел статическую boolean переменную, а в потоке сервиса у меня цикл while, условие продолжения которого я и сделал по этой переменной. Когда надо, я из главного потока делаю эту переменную false и из цикла сервиса у меня программа выходит и поток сервиса завершается.